# Is it possible to encode a series of bytes this way?

Tags: encoding, cryptography, encode, salt

Given:

1. You have a large series of bytes -- call it O.
2. You a pair of bytes (2 bytes) -- call it E.

Is it possible?
Can you somehow encode the O series with the E pair to produce a new series S that is the same size (length) as O, such that given S, and S alone, you can derive the original series O and pair E?

Comment: So you want to write O.size + 2 bytes to O.size object. It is possible (not always) by compression, not encoding.

Comment: Salt is generally _added_ (eg. prepended) to the resulting encrypted/hashed output and is itself _not_ a secret: S = E + hash(E + O), then E (and the hashed portion of the data) can be extracted from S. Same of encryption, except a _secret_ (_not_ E) needs to be used as well.

Comment: If _only_ S is required to restore the original value of O, regardless of E, then there is no secret involved. Might as well use Rot13.

Comment: I am saying that after encoding the series O with bytes E, you get a new series S that is the same size as O.  And given S by itself, you can generate the original series O and E.

Comment: Your asking if it is possible for *n* bytes to contain all the information in *n+2* bytes, and in general the answer is no.

Answer (score 2):

No.

I assume we are talking about completely random data here.

There is the amount of information that can be stored in length of O bytes. Which is the same amount of bytes in S. Every combination of bytes may be a valid dataset.

It is not possible to store more information with the same amount of bytes.

At least for completely random data (like hashes or encrypted data)

As soon as you know anything about the data it's a different story. Non random data means that the data might take up more space than necessary. Therefore there could be space for more information.